# clear screen in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm making a kind of survey app using android and I need to clear the screen to post new questions. Needless to say I cannot keep creating those many activities. I want the flow to go like

Question -> clear screen -> next question and so on.

thanks

Comment: please explain what do you mean by __'screen'__ ?

Comment: To clear screen you can remove views from the screen and add new views to show new questions.This you can achieve through adding views dynamically and remove views before setting new question

Comment: Well if you want to clear a canvas you can use `canvas.drawColor(Color.Black);`

Comment: why you want to clear screen, just change the answer and question text when user press next question. And if your answers vary then create a logic to hide/show answer View according to answer list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `removeView()` or `removeAllViewsInLayout()` functions in ViewGroup to remove views from your layout. **ViewParent** and **ViewGroup** in general can't remove views, so you need to cast it to a layout to do that.

here's the documentation -

[removeView(android.view.View)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeView%28android.view.View%29)

[removeAllViewsInLayout()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeAllViewsInLayout%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view pager in the screen and when someone answers a question , just move the page to show another one with another question. You can even put it in a fragment and have multiple fragments to control movement like say move to a particular question. Look at this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

You can feed your questions from the adapter

Answer (score 0):

You can use view flipper for that

http://www.bogotobogo.com/Android/android9TabWidgetFlipper.php#Flipper

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several ways

1- remove views
2- hide views